# How to plot the confidence interval of times series in R?

Tags: r

I have some problems about drawing confidence interval for time series in R. The data is down below...

```
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(time=c(1980:2019), value=rnorm(40)))
head(dat)
  time      value
1 1980 -1.7196037
2 1981 -0.8135920
3 1982 -0.7451891
4 1983  0.7011315
5 1984  0.5657109
```

I transformed the "value" become time series,

```
ts(dat$value, start=1980, end=2019)
```

but when I try to plot the confidence intervals, it doesn't work,

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean(value)-sd(value), 
                  ymax=mean(value)+sd(value)), alpha=0.05)
```

but it returned...
[image]

Can someone helps me, thanks.

Comment: Your ribbon is just the mean of all data points +/- the sd of all data points. Since you only have one `y` value at each `x` value, what did you expect `sd(value)` to return? `sd(1)` returns `NA`.

Comment: yes, I figure out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure why you converted to `ts` as {ggplot2} can't use it and you didn't assign it back to `dat` in any case.

Also in your data you have only one `y` value at each `x` value. Therefore it doesn't make sense to calculate any error or confidence interval. For example `sd(1)` returns `NA`.

But the main issue is that you are calculating your ribbon off of all the data points so it's just one big rectangle.

If you have multiple `y` values at each `x` value, then you can use `stat_summary()` to calculate the mean and error as desired. See example below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5, 5), y = runif(25))

d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(stat = "summary", size = 2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,
               fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
               fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x), 
               geom = "ribbon", 
               alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>